# Рекурсия для бота угадывания числа

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Написал программу-бот, которая загадывает число, а пользователь должен его угадать. Результат ("больше", "меньше" , "угадали")-выводится с помощью alert. Через цикл все работает как надо, а через рекурсию-нет, alert возвращает "undefined". Как сделать, чтобы работала рекурсия?

```js
let userNum;
let randomNum = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);

function isNum(num) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(num)) && isFinite(num);
}

while (true) {
    userNum = prompt('Введите число');
    if (userNum === null) break;

    if (isNum(userNum)) {
        userNum = +userNum;

        if (userNum > randomNum) {
            alert('Вы ввели большее число');
        } else if (userNum < randomNum) {
            alert('Вы ввели меньшее число');
        } else if (userNum === randomNum) {
            alert('Верно, Вы угадали загаданное число!');
            randomNum = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
        }
    } else {
        alert('Можно вводить только числа');
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите неработающий код с рекурсией

Comment: function guessNumber() должна рекурсивиться

Comment: В этом коде нет рекурсии.

Comment: Смысл такой-я сделал этот бот-через цикл while, всё работает. Но нужно заменить цикл на рекурсию.

Comment: Какой alert возвращает "undefined"?

Comment: Alert возвращал "undefined", когда я while заменил на функцию guessNumber, а потом вызывал её снова alert'ом)

Comment: Ответ ниже не работает вообще, alert ничего не выводит(

Comment: @Summersby Ответ ниже отлично работает. Какой `alert` ничего не выводит?

Comment: @Igor, работает теперь, благодарю. Теперь проблема с выходом из рекурсии, кнопка "отмена" возвращает "Вы ввели меньшее\большее число".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let randomNum = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);

function isNum(num) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(num)) && isFinite(num);
}

function guessNumber() {
  let userNum = prompt('Введите число');
  if (isNum(userNum)) {
    userNum = +userNum;

    if (userNum > randomNum) {
      alert('Вы ввели большее число');
    } else if (userNum < randomNum) {
      alert('Вы ввели меньшее число');
    } else if (userNum === randomNum) {
      alert('Верно, Вы угадали загаданное число!');
      return userNum;
    }
  } else {
    alert('Можно вводить только числа');
  }
  return guessNumber();
}

console.log(guessNumber());
```